# Is there a way to get rid of implied end tags? Angular v4/html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm running this code in my component.html file

```
<p [class.edit]='true'>
  task-details works!
<div [class.edit]='true'>
  <button>Click to mark complete</button>
</div>
</p>
```

and I'm getting the following error when I open console in my browser

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "p". It may happen when the tag has already been 
closed by another tag.
```

The error links to https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags which talks about implied end tags existing.

To try and get around this I delete either the

```
</div>
```

endtag or the

```
</p>
```

endtag. Deleting either one get rid of the error. Also if I get rid of the class description inside and leave a tag that doesn't reference the css it also get rid of the error:

```
<p>
  task-details works!
<div [class.edit]='true'>
  <button>Click to mark complete</button>
</div>
</p>
```

My issue is I want to have the

```
<p [class.edit]='true'>
```

go over my other tag so I can produce a border in my div tag with another larger border around it, which is called by my p tag.

So is there a way to get rid of implied end tags so I can have my div tag inside my p tag or is the only way I can do this is by making the div tag into a child component and then calling it in its immediate parent component?

Comment: AFAIK `<div>` is not valid inside `<p>`

Comment: Thank you Gunter I fixed it